# How to ask appium to drag an element?

Tags: appium-android

I am taking the first steps in mobile automation.

I have a view such as below:

[image]

As you can see, I have a `android.view.ViewGroup` which I should drag an element over it.

My question is:
How can drag the button and take it to the right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the touchAction method :
Just provide the x , y coordinates upto to which you want to drag

```
    new TouchAction(driver)
    .press(PointOption.point(256, 1115))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(2000)))
    .perform()
    .moveTo(PointOption.point(256, 600))
    .release()
    .perform();
```

or if you wanna do it more precisely then you can get the device's x ,y  width and drag it accordingly.